# Terraform Kubernetes metadata name from variable

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I'm trying to inject a variable in the terraform `kubernetes_service` -> `metadata` -> name field. I'm getting the following error

```
│ Error: metadata.0.name a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
│ 
│   with module.collector.kubernetes_deployment.dp_collector,
│   on modules/collector/main.tf line 3, in resource "kubernetes_deployment" "dp_collector":
│    3:     name = var.name
```

Is there any way to do that, from the error description I can't do it I guess.

`var.name = "app_collector"`

Why I want to do this? I have a couple of microservices and deploying is same except ports and names, hence I want to abstract the service in a module.

Comment: Do you have the code that generates the error?

Comment: You should also include the value of `var.name`. Does it conform to the regex in the error message?

Comment: I did some research, it looks like we cannot provide dynamic names for kubernetes_deployment, however its allowed for kubernetes_pod. I may be wrong. Please correct me.

Comment: From the error message the problem seems to be that `app_collector` with an underscore is not a valid hostname, so it can't be used for the name field. I'd give `app-collector` a shot.

Comment: Thanks @RobertNubel it did not work, same error.

Comment: Had a similar problem, my error was comming from the name. As the rule explains, I thought that it was due to the varible, but using a different name that complies with the regex made it pass.